# Parse.com query JSON object

Tags: parse-platform

If I have data stored on Parse.com as a JSON object, isit possible to query into it? For example, I have a column "subject" with data stored as an object:

```
{
  "type": "cal",
  "action": "add",
  "id": "123"
}
```

I want to query for records matching `subject.type = "cal"`. Isit possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
String subname = "\"type\": \"cal\"";    
String[] names = {subname};
query.whereContainedIn("columnname", Arrays.asList(names));
```

you can use above code which help you in finding type="cal" subject in json.
whereContainedIn method will help you for, strings of array is available in column or not.
for using " double qoutes in string \"